# Popup message not coming

Tags: 8

I am using the [Popup After Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_after_login) module to show a pop-up after the users log in.

I want to display a Youtube video on the popup.

The steps I followed after installing the module and enabling it are:

- Go to admin/config/popup_after_login
- Configure it by selecting the role which should see the message
- Enter title, message body and save
- Clear cache and log in with an account to which is assigned that role

For the video, I used the Youtube embed code.

```
        <?php
          print(<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-DYSucV1_9w" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>);
```

The output is not showing.

I checked whether the PHP code is running, adding the following code.

```
        <?php
          $variable = 1+2;
          print($variable);
        ?>
```

Again, only the title was shown, not the message.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The message body is of type text so it accepts "plain text", "filtered HTML" and "Full HTML" by default and it wont run php codes so try to insert this code :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-DYSucV1_9w" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

instead. or if you want to use a php code you can use [PHP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/php), but it is not recommended. PHP filter was removed from Drupal 8 due to security considerations, so try not to add it to your project.

when I checked the module I realized that this module use jquery swal function for pop up, so Iguess you need to change line 10 of its js to something like this :

```
swal.fire(title: result['title'], html:result['message']);
```

this might work.

Comment: i have already installed php filter module for that, and more over the module itself is giving me option to select text format as "php"

Comment: my requirement is to show video popup on first time login, the video url is dynamic need to be fetched using my sql query, how can i do it?

Comment: swal.fire(title: result['title'], html:result['message']); not working

Answer (score 0):

The settings page on /admin/config/popup_after_login allows to select the text format for the message, which by default is *Full HTML*.

> [image: screenshot]

On a fresh Drupal 8 installation, the other available text formats are *Restricted HTML* and *Basic HTML*. All those text formats filter out `<?php`. Looking at the help for the *Full HTML* format (*About text formats*), I get that even HTML attributes are filtered out.

> #### Full HTML
>
> You can align images, videos, blockquotes and so on to the left, right or center. Examples:
>
> - Align an image to the left: `<img src="" data-align="left" />`
> - Align an image to the center: `<img src="" data-align="center" />`
> - Align an image to the right: `<img src="" data-align="right" />`
> - … and you can apply this to other elements as well: `<video src="" data-align="center" />`
>
> You can caption images, videos, blockquotes, and so on. Examples:
>
> - `<img src="" data-caption="This is a caption" />`
> - `<video src="" data-caption="The Drupal Dance" />`
> - `<blockquote data-caption="Dries Buytaert">Drupal is awesome!</blockquote>`
> - `<code data-caption="Hello world in JavaScript.">alert("Hello world!");</code>`

I take that, even removing the `<?php` tags, that HTML markup would not work as expected.

Comment: are you saying that, this module does not support "php decode" or in other words we cannot use php code in message?

Comment: yes by default it is "full html" , but if you choose any thing else and save the configuration , full html is set again. i don;t know why

Comment: No, that with the default settings, a text starting with `<?php` is removed.